# rails4でpolymorphicなモデルにredirect_toするときにurlパラメータを渡す方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

囲碁、オセロ、将棋を遊べるサイトがあります。

それぞれ、Igo、Othello、SyogiモデルはpolymorphicなGameモデルがhas_oneの関係で結びついています。

それぞれのゲームには以下のような、独立したページが存在します。

```
http://example.com/Igo/1
http://example.com/Othello/1
http://example.com/Syogi/1
```

このような条件で、オセロか将棋か囲碁のいずれかが代入されている@gameableポインタを持っているどこかのコントローラで、適切なページヘリダイレクトするには

```
redirect_to @gameable
```

と記述するだけで期待通りのリダイレクトが行われます。
（なぜこれでリダイレクトしてくれるのかは把握してませんが…）

しかし、この条件のリダイレクトに加えてurlパラメータを添えたい場合には
どうすればいいのかわかりません。

ifやswitchなどを利用して@gameableが囲碁なのかオセロなのか将棋なのかを判定し
それぞれリダイレクトするしか方法は無いのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[ ]`で囲むとパラメータが有効になります。

```
redirect_to [@gameable, param: 'hoge']
```

#### 解説

`redirect_to` のメソッド定義は以下のようになっています。

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
```

参考: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to

`redirect_to @gameable, param: 'hoge'` と書くと引数が2つと解釈されます。  
なので、`options`に`@gameable`が、`response_status`に`{param: 'hoge'}`がそれぞれ渡されます。  
これだと意図した挙動になりません。

`redirect_to [@gameable, param: 'hoge']`と書くと引数が1つになります。  
よって、`options`に`[@gameable, param: 'hoge']`が渡されるようになります。

そしてこの引数が `url_for` メソッドに引き渡され、パラメータ付きのURLが生成されます。

参考: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for

Comment: ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to send(@gameable.class.to_s.downcase+'_url', id: @gameable.id, param: 'hoge')
```

で、なんとなく動作しました。
少し無理矢理な気もするので、もう少し良い方法がありましたら
是非教えていただきたいです。